# Java HashMap reverse way

Tags: java, collections, hashmap

I need to have a map between 2 kind of objects, lets say, for demonstrarion purposes, String and Long.

I know a HashMap has an O(1) search performance, which is great. I am using something like this:

```
HashMap<String, Long> a = new HashMap<String, Long>();
```

This works great when I want to search by the key. However, now I do need to also find the key searching by value.

If I start iterating over keys, then I will lose the performance.

The first option I have thought about is to create another HashMap the other way around.

```
HashMap<Long, String> reverseA = new HashMap<Long, String>();
```

And whenever I write in one, write in the other one.

Isn't there an specific class to be able to search by keys and by values, with that great performance?

Should I create my own class with both HashMaps?

Any other solution?

Comment: Perhaps Guava's [BiMap](https://github.com/google/guava/wiki/NewCollectionTypesExplained#bimap) contains what you're looking for.

Comment: But of course they key is unique and the value is maybe not so

Comment: @ScaryWombat: Well, if the `reverseA` map is an option, then the values better be unique or there will be a bit of inconsistency.

Comment: If you don't want to use third API, why not filter the map using new Streaming API which does not have overhead, unless you do a terminal call?

Comment: Why not use 2 HashMaps? It would be better than adding a new dependency to Guava just for this one case.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use Guava [BiMap](https://google.github.io/guava/releases/23.0/api/docs/com/google/common/collect/BiMap.html) :

```
BiMap<String, Long> map = HashBiMap.create();
map.put("a", 1L);
map.put("b", 2L);
map.put("c", 3L);

System.out.println(map.get("b")); // 2L
System.out.println(map.inverse().get(2L)); // "b"
```

An other alternative is Apache commons [BidiMap](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-collections/apidocs/org/apache/commons/collections4/BidiMap.html) :

```
BidiMap<String, Long> map = new DualHashBidiMap<>();
map.put("a", 1L);
map.put("b", 2L);
map.put("c", 3L);

System.out.println(map.get("b")); // 2L
System.out.println(map.inverseBidiMap().get(2L)); // "b"
```

Answer (score 0):

Java itself doesn't offer anything, but Guava has [BiMap](https://google.github.io/guava/releases/19.0/api/docs/com/google/common/collect/BiMap.html), which has an inverse view that supports efficient reverse lookups.